# Simulate high screen resolution Windows

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I'm looking for a way to simulate a higher resolution on a Windows server than supported by the graphics card or screen.

A good illustration would be a Linux server that you configure with TigerVNC at a high resolution, so when you connect with your client, you get the resolution you want on your client screen.

In that sense, it's irrelevant whether the machine can display the resolution locally, as long as all applications operate on the higher resolution internally.

The only solutions I could find thus far are browser plugins tailored for website developers or screenshot tools. I need something that does the same for (all) other applications.

Comment: Sorry, are you asking how to change a the settings for an Remote Desktop session?

Comment: No, the setting of the resolution that the machine is internally running on. I.E, if you had a monitor & a graphics card supporting it, that's what you would see when plugging in. Except you don't have either.

Comment: Going with your TigerVNC example, you can achieve the same on Windows using the builtin Remote Desktop. Just connect and in the client select the desired resolution. It can be as big as the local monitor(s) or even bigger (save the connection and use a text editor to change the resolution in it).